# Explicit Address Manipulation in C++

Tags: c++, pointers

Please check out the following func and its output

```
void main()
{
    Distance d1;
    d1.setFeet(256);
    d1.setInches(2.2);

    char *p=(char *)&d1;
    *p=1;

    cout<< d1.getFeet()<< " "<< d1.getInches()<< endl;
}
```

The class `Distance` gets its values thru `setFeet` and `setInches`, passing `int` and `float` arguments respectively. It displays the values through through the `getFeet` and `getInches` methods.

However, the output of this function is `257 2.2`. Why am I getting these values?

Comment: Please clarify what your question is. What is the problem you're having with your code?

Comment: Could you clarify the code? Like, the `p=1` is meaningless, if the compiler would even accept it. And, what is the question?

Comment: It may be worded badly but this is a valid question. What happens when I write to memory via a pointer. We have all done it.

Comment: @Mike p =1 is well defined. it assigned the value to 1 to the object pointed at by p. Note char is an integral type.

Comment: OP has simply had his *s eaten by not formatting code properly. Besides that this seems to be a valid question, except the result is most likely unspecified, depending on the internal representation of integers (endianness). If you get 257, then it means 256 is represented as 00010000, and by setting the first byte to 1, it becomes 01010000 => 257

Comment: I've edited the question to represent what I *think* the OP meant. Hopefully it reads as a proper question now.

Comment: @JS Bangs:  It now reads like a reasonable question.  Voting to reopen.

Comment: In any case, this is something one has to be aware of when they get the temptation to treat something as simply a bunch of bytes. I wonder, what the OP expected to see.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a really bad idea:

```
char *p=(char *)&d1;
*p=1;
```

Your code should never make assumptions about the internal structure of the class.  If your class had any virtual functions, for example, that code would cause a crash when you called them.

I can only conclude that your `Distance` class looks like this:

```
class Distance {
    short feet;
    float inches;
public:
    void setFeet(...
};
```

When you `setFeet(256)`, it sets the high byte (MSB) to 1 (256 = 1 * 2^8) and the low byte (LSB) to 0.  When you assign the value `1` to the `char` at the address of the `Distance` object, you're forcing the first byte of the `short` representing feet to 1.  On a little-endian machine, the low byte is at the lower address, so you end up with a `short` with both bytes set to 1, which is `1 * 2^8 + 1 = 257`.

On a big-endian machine, you would still have the value 256, but it would be purely coincidental because you happen to be forcing a value of 1 on a byte that would already be 1.

However, because you're using undefined behavior, depending on the compiler and the compile options, you might end up with literally anything.  A famous expression from comp.lang.c is that such undefined behavior could "cause demons to fly out of your nose".

Comment: Demons flying out of my nose I can handle. It's when undefined behaviour produces the "expected" results that I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2):

You are illegally munging memory via the 'p' pointer.

The output of the program is **undefined**; as you are directly manipulating memory that is owned by an object through a pointer of another type without regard to the underlying types.

Your code is somewhat like this:

```
struct Dist
{
    int     x;
    float   y;
};

union Plop
{
    Dist    s;  // Your class
    char    p;  // The type you are pretending to use via 'p'
};

int main()
{
    Plop    p;

    p.s.x   = 5;    // Set up the Dist structure.
    p.s.y   = 2.3;

    p.p     = 1;    // The value of s is now undefined.
                    // As you have scribbled over the memory used by s.
}
```

Comment: Actually, OP's code's behavior need not necessarily be undefined. Accessing an object through the pointer to `char` is explicitly allowed by the standard.

Comment: @avakar That only makes sense if you use `offsetof` or similar to discover the actual address of a public member.  Accessing the object's memory without discovering the member offset has to be undefined behavior or such internals as v-table pointers would not be possible.

Comment: Yes, any POD can be accessed and modified through `char*`, but you don't know the representation of its members. Except when the first member is a `char`, the behavior is undefined when accessing the first member afterwards by its type even for PODs if have written a trap representation (so assuming the worst, it's always undefined). If not, the value is still unspecified since you don't know the mapping between bits and values of the member. If the first member is a char and if the struct is a POD, then it's perfectly valid code.

Comment: @avakar: Thats like saying poining a loaded gun at your own head is explicitly allowed by the law. True. But not a good idea.

Comment: @litb: also I think if the first value is a `signed char` or `unsigned char`. Writing 1 to either of those has defined behaviour, and IIRC they aren't allowed to have trap representations either (and must be the same size as char).

Comment: Yes, *if* you write a trap representation, and then read it, then you are doing UB. But since those types cannot have traps (not sure about `signed char` here, though), this cannot happen for them, so you can safely read. But the value you will read will be unspecified (you are guaranteed that this will read *some* value, but i don't think the value is required to be anything in particular).

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour based on the code given is going to be very unpredictable. Setting the first byte of `d1`'s data could potentially clobber a vptr, compiler-specific memory, the sign/exponent of a floating point value, or LSB or MSB of an integer, all depending on the definition of Distance.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you think doing *p = 1 will set one of the internal data members (presumably 'feet') in the Distance object.  It may work, but (afaik) you've got no guarantees that the feet member is at the first address of the object, is of the correct size (unless its type is also char) or that it's aligned correctly.

If you want to do that why not make the 'feet' member public and do:

```
d1.feet = 1;
```

Comment: Indeed, but there might be valid reasons he wants to directly modify the contents, and treat it more like a struct than a class (I appreciate there's very little difference between them in c++).

Answer (score 0):

Another thing, to comment on the program:  don't use `void main()`.  It isn't standard, and it offers you no benefits.  It will make people not take you as seriously when asking C or C++ questions, and could cause programs to not compile, or not work properly.

The C++ Standard, in 3.6.1 paragraph 2, says that `main()` always returns `int`, although the implementation may offer variations with different arguments.

This would be a good time to break the habit.  If you're learning from a book that uses `void main()`, the book is unreliable.  See about getting another book, if only for reference.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are new to programming and could use some help with basic concepts.

It's good that you are looking for that, but SO may not be the right place to get it.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The Definition of class is

```
class Distance{
    int feet;
    float inches;
    public:
//...functions
};
```

now the int feet would be 00000001 00000000 (2 bytes) where the zeros would occupy lower address in Little Endian so the char *p will be 00000000.. when u make *p=1, the lower byte becomes 00000001 so the int variable now is 00000001 00000001 which is exactly 257!